# ADFS on premises with Laravel and generation of Metafile

Tags: laravel, saml-2.0, adfs

I've requirement of configuration of ADFS on premises with an Laravel application. In first I understood that it may be ADFS Azure but we had clarification that they don't need it with ADFS azure but ADFS on premises. ADFS on premises is new to me i don't have idea how that can be used with Laravel.

As part of requirement they told me I need to generate some meta file i am using https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2 it has route to generate metafile but dont understand if that will do the work.

After some searching i found a blog https://adsy2010.blogspot.com/2018/04/laravel-simplesaml-with-adfs-setup.html which explains the same

But I didn't understand from where we can use ADFS console.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

- Open Server Manager on the computer that is running AD FS.
- Choose AD FS
- Tools
- AD FS Management

or just search for "Active Directory Federation Services" in the Windows search panel.

Comment: Hi @rbrayb 
Do you mean where the site is hosted .. ? Server where the site is hosted is linux server and i am not getting that if it will have server manager

Comment: No the Windows server that is running ADFS.

Comment: Actually that is the main confusion for as the hosted site is on linux server..so here i am not getting which Windows server i need to check on

Comment: Do a network trace on the application and see which AFDS server it contacts.

Comment: From our side they are expecting to have a metafile only ..I have used above mentioned package for the same if i can give them same metafile do it will work ..?
As what are you mentioning i think i need to give them metafile as ADFS is working on there server or network

Comment: If ADFS is on their side, yes, you give them your metadata,

Comment: Yes ADFS is on their side ..thanks man for clarity !